# Hibernate + Logback, not logging in file

Tags: java, hibernate, file, logging, logback

I'm using Hibernate 3.1.3 and Logback (classic+core) 1.1.7.

Here are my logback.xml

```
<appender name="hibernate-sql"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/hibernate-sql.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <FileNamePattern>c:/temp/hibernate-sql.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
      <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
      <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

</appender>

  <logger name="org.hibernate.hql">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="hibernate-sql"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="hibernate-sql"/>
  </logger>

  <root level="TRACE">
    <!--<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>-->
    <!--<appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>-->
  </root>
```

I get SQL logged in my IDE console (due to `hibernate.show_sql = true`), but not in logs/hibernate-sql.log. The file is well created but remains empty.

Here is the debug info about logback :

```
12:34:43,301 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
12:34:43,301 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
12:34:43,301 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/******/logback.xml]
12:34:43,535 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
12:34:43,543 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [hibernate-sql]
12:34:43,668 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@77e4c80f - Will use zip compression
12:34:43,678 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[hibernate-sql] - Active log file name: logs/hibernate-sql.log
12:34:43,679 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[hibernate-sql] - File property is set to [logs/hibernate-sql.log]
12:34:43,684 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.hql level set to TRACE
12:34:43,684 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [hibernate-sql] to Logger[org.hibernate.hql]
12:34:43,685 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.SQL level set to TRACE
12:34:43,685 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [hibernate-sql] to Logger[org.hibernate.SQL]
12:34:43,686 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to TRACE
12:34:43,686 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
12:34:43,687 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@36f0f1be - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Why is it logging in the console but not in my file, even if it creates well the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `debug="true"` to your logback.xml file like described [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#dumpingStatusData). It will help understand, how your logging is configured really.

Comment: I add debug and add the log about logback in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Your appender name is not correct

```
<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
```

It should be `<appender-ref ref="hibernate-sql"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I got changing some parts of your original code, this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
   <appender name="hibernate-sql" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>.../logs/hibernate-sql.log</file> <!-- Here i add the full path to log file -->
      <encoder>
         <Pattern>%green(%d) %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{0}) mdc=%X{id} %msg %n</Pattern>
      </encoder>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
         <FileNamePattern>c:/temp/hibernate-sql.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
         <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
         <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
      </rollingPolicy>
      <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
         <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
      </triggeringPolicy>
   </appender>
   <appender name="SERVER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file></file> <!-- Full path to log file -->
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
         <!-- rollover daily -->
         <FileNamePattern></FileNamePattern>
      </rollingPolicy>
      <encoder>
         <Pattern>%green(%d) %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{0}) mdc=%X{id} %msg %n</Pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>
   <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <FileNamePattern>c:/temp/hibernate-sql.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
      <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
      <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
   </rollingPolicy>
   <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
   </triggeringPolicy>
   <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"> <!-- Here i changed your block -->
      <appender-ref ref="hibernate-sql" />
   </logger>
   <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="SERVER" />
   </root>
</configuration>
```

Basically, i add the full path to log and changed the 'hibernate-sql' configuration. You can try to adapt to your case

Comment: @Jon Change your first line: <appender name="hibernate-sql" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> to: <appender name="hibernate-sql" filename="logs/hibernate-sql.log" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> and exclude: <file>logs/hibernate-sql.log</file>

Comment: @Julios Dias : Doing this, I get a java.lang.IllegalStateException: The "File" option must be set

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

To get the logs with `Logback 1.1.7` and `Hibernate 3.1.3`, we need:

1. `slf4j-api 1.7.5`
2. `jul-to-slf4j 1.7.6`
3. `jul-over-slf4j 1.7.6`

Other versions may work too but the most important things is the jul-over-slf4j dependency.